# Ordering in properties file reshuffled after doing a saving data to the properties file

Tags: java, sorting, properties

I have a properties file which i read information from to populate a labels and JTextFields. Upon saving, i am supposed to write these information back into my properties file, but upon saving, the properties file is messed up and becomes difficult to read.

I'm not sure how to sort the data, since the properties are unsorted.

This is how i saved my properties file.

```
public void saveChanges(){
  try{
    fileopstrm = new FileOutputStream(file);
    props.store(fileopstrm, "Updated");
    fileopstrm.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

My properties file are formatted like so initially(sample):

```
Name=abc
Age=45

address.block=11
address.street=123
address.postalcode=111

info.hobby=aaa
info.interest=bbb
info.details=ccc
```

But after storing to the properties file, it becomes like this:

```
Name=abc
address.postalcode=111
info.details=ccc
Age=45
info.hobby=aaa
address.street=123
info.interest=bbb
address.block=11
```

It becomes difficult to read and edit manually in the future. New information may also be added at a later time, for example "address.zzz=aaa" or "info.aaa=qqq".

Comment: Does it matter if the data is sorted? All the properties are made up of key and value pairs, so the order should not matter at all and should not impact how you read it back into your JTextFields? You can always re-order everything once you have read it from the properties file. Edit: using `storeToXML` will help somewhat.

Comment: Hi sorifiend, from the program's standpoint no it does not matter. But should a user wish to modify the properties file manually it will because it makes it hard to find.